# Can a Cavalier choose Eagle Mount at first level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mount

A level one [Cavalier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier) receives a [mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/#TOC-Mount-Ex-) as a special class feature.

Can  cavailers get riding eagles or hawks at first level?

> #### Riding Eagle
>
> **Special:** A cavalier can choose this as a mount.
>   **Size** Large
>   **Speed** 10 ft., fly 80 ft. (average)
>  
>   **AC** +0 natural armor
>   **Attack** bite (1d6), 2 talons (1d4)
>  
>   **Ability Scores:**
>  
>   **Str** 14 
>   **Dex** 13 
>   **Con** 12 
>   **Int** 2  
>   **Wis** 12 
>   **Cha** 8  
>   **Special Qualities** low-light vision.
>
> #### Riding Hawk
>
> **Special:** A cavalier can choose this as a mount.
>   **Size** Medium
>   **Speed** 10 ft., fly 60 ft. (average)
>  
>   **AC** +1 natural armor
>   **Attack** bite (1d6), 2 talons (1d4)
>  
>   **Ability Scores:**
>  
>   **Str** 12 
>   **Dex** 13 
>   **Con** 14 
>   **Int** 2  
>   **Wis** 12 
>   **Cha** 6  
>   **Special Qualities** low-light vision.

Comment: Just to make sure: the question's asking *Are these homebrew animal companions reasonable mounts for a Medium level 1 cavalier?* Is that accurate? If so, are they to be evaluated in a vacuum as if these flying mounts were suddenly were made available to *Pathfinder* PCs at large in any campaign or, instead, in a specific setting like a micronations on an archipelago or a war against dragons?

Comment: (Also, it's only Small cavaliers who can at level 4 also pick dog or boar; Medium cavaliers typically remain (*ahem*) saddled with the camel or horse their entire careers *both* because that's what the text says *and* because each is a "creature… that he is capable of riding and is suitable as a mount.")

Comment: (1st comment) 3PP sounds more credible, but yes Pathfinder at large. Granted there are riding Owls for 6,500gp base game so using homebrew in a pejorative sense is a little heavy imo(2nd comment) That is why it seems funny to be level restricted because some of the flavor is having your trusted steed 'patsy' throughout your career, and not just switch to a completely different animal at 4th level.

Comment: (I *never* use the terms *homebrew* nor *house rule* pejoratively, and I'm ashamed of our hobby whenever either term is. Other media *celebrate* innovative and interesting homebrewing and house ruling, and that our hobby too often makes people feel like they're doing it wrong if they do homebrew or house rule is bad and stupid.)

Comment: I'm not sure being able to *buy* a riding owl for 6,500 gp at later levels and actually *having* a scaling flying mount at level 1 are equivalent. Is that the only point of comparison available? Or is it just as fair to compare such a mount to other possible animal companions? And, on the second point, druids *are* kind of expected to swap out their animal companions when they need to, and, while it's a little bit more of a trial for a cavalier, the idea's essentially the same: if a cavalier knows the next 10 levels'll spent in the desert, she might want to swap her horse for a camel, y'know?

Comment: You're right they aren't equivalent because is depends on what the number of HD for the Giant Owl listed for purchase (6,000 gp btw) is, and is it of the magical beast variant listed in the beastiary? So why not take a look at camels, and horses? The horse has better AC and DMG, while the camel has better AC and the ability to inflict sickened(didn't see anything about Fort save) on a successful **ranged** touch attack. Both of them increase STR and CON with ability score increases. While the eagle only gets STR.

Comment: In a nut shell the riding eagle trades AC, landspeed, damage, hp, and scent to be able to fly(average) at level 1 which is not the same as the fly(good) spell. Also, because it is a large creature it flies at a -2. If you allocated all of the skill points it has into only fly you would be able to auto pass a DC 10 fly check at 10th level(9th with acrobatic feat, 6th with acrobatic and skill focus feats) in light or moderate wind conditions.

Comment: At level one more "...like trying to fly a freight train, gross overload, trim characteristics all shot to hell, I nearly broke both my arms trying to keep her level."

Comment: It sounds like you've a very strong opinion on this already. Is it strong enough to warrant self-answering your own question?

Comment: What is the source of this riding eagle? I cannot find it anywhere. Your entire premise here (that which mounts you are allowed is based purely on their size) is quite simply incorrect, but it is very difficult to prove a negative. It would be much more effective to attempt to track down that eagle and see if its authors detailed the rules for when and how a cavalier could have it as a mount.

Comment: @KRyan I couldn't find them either! That's *so* weird. Chewbapoclypse, sorry for not understanding the question! Without being able to locate them, I assumed these mounts were homebrew. Sincerely, my apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @chewbapoclypse good call on large sized with -2 penalty, i completely overlooked it.

Comment: @KRyan [this is the source](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8yru?Cavalier-Mounts)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, any animal is available if your GM allows it

The core of the **Mount** class ability is that any mount your GM feels that is suitable to your character can be used as a mount, as said on it's description:

> **Mount (Ex)**
>
> A cavalier gains the service of a loyal and trusty steed to carry him into battle. This mount functions as a druid’s animal companion, using the cavalier’s level as his effective druid level. **The creature must be one that he is capable of riding and is suitable as a mount**.
>
> A Medium cavalier can select a camel or a horse. A Small cavalier can select a pony or wolf, but can also select a boar or a dog if he is at least 4th level. **The GM might approve other animals as suitable mounts**.

Normally, this mount is a horse-like animal, four-legged and usually one size category larger. But the class ability does not restrict your character in no way, and the GM is free to allow any mount that would make sense for him.

That mount is not restricted to only one of those listed as examples, unlike the [Ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/)'s animal companion, for example, that has a restricted list (even so, I know a lot of GMs don't enforce it based on community feedback):

> A ranger who selects an animal companion can choose from the following list: badger, bird, camel, cat (small), dire rat, dog, horse, pony, snake (viper or constrictor), or wolf.

That said, we can only tell you that GM's normally approve those listed on the *Mount* class ability, but GM's should keep in mind that the ability is giving them *extra power* to change the available mounts to cavalier characters without actually *house ruling* to favor your character.

For an official source of this, on the *Players Guide* of each Adventure Path, there are tips and hints about animal companions and mounts available specifically for that adventure, based on the geographical location of the adventure, usually restricting the options available. But sometimes also expanding the options for druids, rangers, cavaliers and hunters.

For example, the [Iron God's Players Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy98lf?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-Iron-Gods-Players-Guide) (*free download*) says the following:

> **Animal Companions and Familiars**
>
> The following animal companions can all be found in
>   Numeria: antelope, aurochs, badger, bear, bird, boar,
>   dire bat, dire rat, dog, elk, giant weasel, horse, mastodon,
>   moose, pony, ram, stag, viper, and wolf.
>
> The following familiars are commonly found serving
>   wizards and witches in Numeria: armadillo, bat, cat,
>   centipede, fox, goat, giant f lea, hawk, hedgehog, owl, pig,
>   raccoon, rat, raven, scorpion, skunk, squirrel, f lying squirrel,
>   toad, viper, and weasel.
>
> In addition to these suggestions, **three new alien animals**
>   are presented in the bestiary of the first volume of the
>   Iron Gods Adventure Path. **Talk to your GM about these**
>   animals and see if they are a good fit for your character
>   and campaign.

Here, the three animals (petromin, pilo and sorico) are alien from Golarion and actually come from another planet, but are available to be selected for characters playing Iron Gods (set in [Numeria](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Numeria)).

### Riding Eagles are a bad choice for Medium-sized characters

Note that even lightly armored characters might make this impossible due to weight and the [carrying capacity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/) of the (3PP) riding eagle (116 lbs. light load). Even the lightest medium characters on the core rulebook will weight *at least* 95 lbs ([female human](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human/), female elves closely behind with 96 lbs), add a bare minimum of equipment and the mount will already be on a medium load (-3 on fly checks).

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\mbox{Strength Score}& \mbox{Light Load} & \mbox{Medium Load} & \mbox{Heavy Load}
\\\hline
\mbox{14} & \mbox{116 lbs. or less} & \mbox{117–232lbs.} & \mbox{232–350 lbs.}
\\\hline
\end{array}

With average fly speed (+0 on checks) large size (-2 on checks) and dex 13 (+1 on checks), you are looking at an excuse to [plummet to the ground](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly/) in combat. **I would advise against it**. The best possible check at first level is a **bonus of +3** (+1 dex modifier, 1 skill rank at 1st level, +3 class skill, +3 [skill focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/skill-focus-final), -2 penalty from size, -3 penalty from weight), which is not enough to automatically pass on DC 10 checks in stressful situations. Any extra equipment, such as the character also carrying a medium load, will only make this harder on your mount (-6 penalty on heavy load).

A [Roc animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/#TOC-Roc) is a much better choice in the long run (7th and up), though they also start with a very low str score (str 12) and being medium-sized creatures (large at 7th with +8 strength). They will have about 22 strength at 7th level (+2 from class advancements), which is enough to carry a medium-sized cavalier with some armor, weapons and his equipment, as long as he doesn't exaggerate. But you will not be riding this mount at the earlier levels (1-6) without the help of magic.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
\mbox{Strength Score}& \mbox{Light Load} & \mbox{Medium Load} & \mbox{Heavy Load}
\\\hline
\mbox{22} & \mbox{346 lbs. or less} & \mbox{347–692 lbs.} & \mbox{693–1040 lbs.}
\\\hline
\end{array}

Comment: [It's possible to read the encumbrance rules as forbidding a creature from flying at all with a medium or greater load.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/57020/8610) I'm pretty sure that's how it work in *D&D 3.5e*, but *Pathfinder* buries such info pretty deep.

Comment: @HeyICanChan if i had to guess, i would say that rule is gone in pathfinder.

Comment: That is the rule on the Pathfinder Society though: *"A medium or heavy load counts as medium or heavy armor for the purpose of abilities or skills that are restricted by armor. "* Both medium armor and medium load will prevent a flying mount from flying, but that restriction is not applied to flying creatures in general.

Comment: [*Flying mounts can’t fly in medium or heavy barding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/animals-animal-gear/) and [*A medium or heavy load counts as medium or heavy armor for the purpose of abilities or skills that are restricted by armor*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/) are both part of the basic *d20PFSRD.* If you really want to differentiate between a flying creatures in general and flying mounts specifically, I guess that's a thing, but those hairs are too fine for me to split.

Comment: @HeyICanChan the difference i was pointing out is that there *are* flying creatures on medium load on the bestiary.

Comment: A [Solar Archon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/angel/solar/) wears a full plate with no special abilities that allows them to fly on loads higher than light. It even takes a reduced fly speed while wearing his armor.

Comment: I don't know how to reconcile the rules that I've cited above with the examples the text provides. Do we just shrug and say, "Whatever?"

Comment: Personally, I don't even enforce that rule, it sounds like something restrictive that wasn't necessary to exist now that we have a skill that decides how well a creature can fly. Weight is already a big problem to flying creatures (penalties), so enforcing that they cannot have more than light capacity shouldn't be needed anymore. I marked all 4 or 5 threads about this for FAQ candidates, so someday we might get an official answer.

Comment: @ShadowKras schweet table. and the mounts from Numeria sound cool af, have to take a look

Answer (score 1):

## At level 1 a Medium cavalier can pick the riding eagle and a Small cavalier can pick the riding hawk

To serve as the [cavalier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier)'s [mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier#TOC-Mount-Ex-), "[t]he creature must be one that [the cavalier] is capable of riding and is suitable as a mount." Normally, a mount must be at least one size category than the rider, so the riding hawk (and pony and wolf and boar and dog) can't typically be a Medium cavalier's mount. However, the player of a Medium cavalier can ask the GM if Medium mounts are available to his PC if, for instance, the PC possesses the feat [Undersized Mount](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/undersized-mount-combat/).

There is, so far as I'm aware, no rule like *The mount must be one size category larger than the Cavalier until the cavalier is level 4 when it may be the same size category.* The cavalier's mounts are organized by the size category of the *cavalier*: "A Medium cavalier can select a camel or a horse" (both Large mounts), and, "A Small cavalier can select a pony or wolf, but can also select a boar or a dog if he is at least 4th level" (all Medium mounts, the boar and dog likely being considered more powerful—hence the delay in acquisition—than the pony and wolf).

And while "[t]he GM might approve other animals as suitable mounts," the riding eagle and riding hawk *can fly*, which, at level 1, is a red flag for many GMs, despite the former's carrying capacity of 116 lbs. and the latter's of 43 lbs. (making for some skinny and lightly armored on-the-wing cavaliers!). So while these mounts may be *possible* if the GM's given blanket approval for third-party material, the GM may still say *No*, usually because flying at low levels obviates many typical threats. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97444/8610).)

Comment: that was probably the text I had read @Undersized Mount, thanks!!!